# Why does pygame load slow?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a simple project that display a "button" with an image,a text and a background color:

```
import os
os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import requests
import io

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GRAY = (200, 200, 200)

class Main_window:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    def draw(self):
        Btn1 = Button(0,0,200,200,"hello",color=RED, text="test",text_color=BLACK)
    def mainLoop(self):
        done = False
        while not done:
            eventlist = pygame.event.get()
            for ev in eventlist:
                if ev.type == QUIT:
                    done = True
                if ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    Button.getButton(ev)
        pygame.quit()

class Button:
    Buttons = []

    def __init__(self, left, top, w, h,function,color=RED, text="", text_color = BLACK):
        self.left = left
        self.top = top
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.right = self.left+w
        self.bottom = self.top+h
        self.function = function
        surf1 = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        surf1.fill(color)
        rect1 = pygame.Rect(left, top, w, h)
        main.screen.blit(surf1, rect1)
        Button.Buttons.append(self)
        if text != "":
            font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('chalkduster.ttf', 72)
            text1 = font1.render(text, True, text_color)
            text_rect = text1.get_rect(center=(int(w/2), int(h/2)))
            main.screen.blit(text1, text_rect)
        image_url = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/31/31990.png"
        r = requests.get(image_url)
        img = io.BytesIO(r.content)
        image = pygame.image.load(img)
        image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (w, h))
        main.screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def getButton(event):
        for i in Button.Buttons:
            x, y = event.pos
            if x>=i.left and x<=i.right and y<=i.bottom and y>=i.top:
                eval(i.function+"()")

def hello():
    print("hello")

main = Main_window()
main.draw()
main.mainLoop()
```

that's works fine but the problem is that when i launch the game it load the main window, wait some time(something like 1 second) and then load the button.I tried to add more button and it loaded them one at a time.I don't undestand why.

Comment: You are downloading the image from the internet. Try using an image on disk.

Comment: ... and don't load the image for each button instance, but once at initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Fixes

1. Use a local image rather than an image sent with requests
2. It loads slowly maybe because of the draw function of the MainWindow class.
   Try this in the main loop function

```py
    def mainLoop(self):
        done = False
        while not done:
            eventlist = pygame.event.get()
            for ev in eventlist:
                if ev.type == QUIT:
                    done = True
                if ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    Button.getButton(ev)
            self.draw()
            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.quit()
```

And at the end

```py
main = Main_window()
main.mainLoop()
```

So you don't have to call `main.draw()` because it is already being called in the main loop.